# How to reshape numpy array in this way?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

I want to reshape `a` into `b`, how to quickly do it?

Basically, when reshaping the array, how to always use the first item in each group, then the second item, then the third one?

Input:

```
import numpy as np

# 3 repeats, each has 2 variables, each has 4 times
a=np.array([[['r1_v1_t1','r1_v1_t2','r1_v1_t3','r1_v1_t4'],
            ['r1_v2_t1','r1_v2_t2','r1_v2_t3','r1_v2_t4']],

[['r2_v1_t1','r2_v1_t2','r2_v1_t3','r2_v1_t4'],
            ['r2_v2_t1','r2_v2_t2','r2_v2_t3','r2_v2_t4']],

[['r3_v1_t1','r3_v1_t2','r3_v1_t3','r3_v1_t4'],
            ['r3_v2_t1','r3_v2_t2','r3_v2_t3','r3_v2_t4']]
            ])

# 4 times, each has 3 repeats, each has 2 variables
b=np.array([[['r1_v1_t1','r1_v2_t1'],['r2_v1_t1','r2_v2_t1'],['r3_v1_t1','r3_v2_t1']],
[['r1_v1_t2','r1_v2_t2'],['r2_v1_t2','r2_v2_t2'],['r3_v1_t2','r3_v2_t2']],
[['r1_v1_t3','r1_v2_t3'],['r2_v1_t3','r2_v2_t3'],['r3_v1_t3','r3_v2_t3']],
[['r1_v1_t4','r1_v2_t4'],['r2_v1_t4','r2_v2_t4'],['r3_v1_t4','r3_v2_t4']]])

# 4 times, each has 2 variables, each has 3 repeats
#print(a.T)

#print(np.reshape(a,(4,3,2), order='F')) not work
#print(np.reshape(a,(4,3,2))) not work
```

Comment: Could you not just do `a.reshape(b.shape, order='F')`?

Comment: ```b=a.T``` Just transpose it.

Comment: thank you! The transpose works! Sorry, I was actually trying to solve a more complex problem, so I re-edited the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap the array's axes so the shape of `a` matches the shape of `b`.  Numpy's [swapaxes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html#numpy.swapaxes) can achieve this:

```
new_a = np.swapaxes( np.swapaxes(a,0,2) ,1,2)
```

You can test that this `new_a` is equivalent to `b`:

```
print (new_a == b).all()  # True
```

Here's a working [gist](https://gist.github.com/braunagn/6aab5c7a4e4a20aca8013a1870eecfac).

Comment: fantastic! so powerful!